# Swift 2.2 : extend array to implement protocol but only for specific Element type

Tags: swift2

Consider the following code, that uses Generics to implement a Factory that creates Objects as long as they implement the ProtocolDataConstructed :

```
protocol ProtocolDataConstructed {
    init?(data: String?)
}


class MyObject : NSObject, ProtocolDataConstructed {
    required convenience init?(data: String?) {
        //call super's
        self.init()
        //nothing to construct if string is invalid
        guard let data = data else { return nil }
        //do stuff here with the string to create this instance of MyObject
        //...
    }
}

class Factory {
    static func createFromJson<T : ProtocolDataConstructed> (data : String?) -> T? {
        //...
        return T(data : data)
    }
}

//Works perfectly ! :

    let myObject : MyObject? = Factory.createFromJson("sometestdatastring")
```

What I want is that I am able to parse also an array of ProtocolDataConstructed objects like so :

```
   let myArrayOfObjects : [MyObject]? = Factory.createFromJson("sometestdataString")
```

So I want Array to implement the ProtocolDataConstructed IF and ONLY IF the elements in the array themselves implement the ProtocolDataConstructed

So something like:

```
extension Array : ProtocolDataConstructed where Element == ProtocolDataConstructed {
        required convenience init?(data: String?) {
...
    }
}
```

However this compiles with the following error:

```
Extension of type 'Array' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause
Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Element' non-generic
```

Is there another way that this can be done? Another syntax maybe?

Comment: extension Array  where Element : ProtocolDataConstructed{   } Check this.Is this what you want.

Comment: but this does not say that Array itself implement the ProtocolDataConstructed, only that the elements have to, no? So this would not work...

Comment: extension Array where Element : ProtocolDataConstructed { ... }
and then  let test : [MyObject]? = Factory.createFromJson("sometestdataString") says "Generic parameter "T" could not be inferred". I think that is because of my previous, comment what you suggest does not tell that the Array itself implements ProtocolDataConstructed